# Ionic 2 Storage does not work on iOS

Tags: ios, html, ionic2

I am using @ionic/storage as it looked quite promising after reading about it in the [V2 Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/).

I use Chrome on my Windows 10 laptop so things appeared to be working perfectly fine at first. However, when I tested it on iPad, or even Firefox on my laptop, I was surprised to find out it did not work.

I was able to resolve the issue on Firefox by removing the sqlite plugin (I thought I will add it when I am ready for native testing):

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-sqlite-storage --save
```

Sadly, storage still doesn't work on the iPad. I tested it on Safari and Chrome. I am unable to debug this given the lack of developer tools or console.

I am quite frustrated how Apple makes you dependent on using a Mac to develop on their devices.

How do I go about fixing and debugging this?

I first import storage in Ionic 2:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Then to save the data, I do this:

```
this.storage.set(pk, JSON.stringify(reportObj));
```

Where pk is just a unique key, and reportObj is an object that I stringify before storing. Again, keep in mind this just doesn't work in iOS.

Thanks.

**Update:**

So I managed to run the app in Safari and found out that .set actually works and the data gets stored in WebSQL. However, the get does not seem to work and I wasn't able to get any useful errors in the console.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Done, but do you think its the code given Ionic 2 is meant to be cross platform, and the code works on all devices by iOS.

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after a lot of trial and error, I found out that the problem is not really with Storage. There appears to be some other issue with my UI, where it doesn't seem to work on iOS.

I decided to answer the part about testing the app on iOS while in development if you are not a Mac user. The best way for this appears to be to use Ionic View. You can use this simply by typing:

```
ionic upload
```

Make sure you create your account. In your iPad or iPhone, you can then download Ionic View app from iTune, sign in, and the app will appear there.

As you upload your code, simply upload again and almost instantly the app would upload on the device as you click Sync.

Hope other Windows users benefit from this.